# Xpath or CSS generators for Firefox or Chrome

Tags: css, selenium, user-interface, xpath, spy

I'm not having much luck finding plugins that will help me with my Selenium webdriver development. Firebug for FF is no longer supported. Selenium IDE is also not working for me. I have tried several plugins for both FF & Chrome, but not having any luck finding something that will generate xpath or CSS strings. I am also open to any stand alone gui spy apps (not just plugins). Recommendations appreciated!

Comment: The path or css selector made by plugin are often too long and complex. Not recommend to use plugin for that.

Comment: Your best bet is to just read tutorials for XPath and CSS selectors. Handcrafted ones (done properly) are going to be much better, much less brittle that ones created by some plugin, etc.

Answer (score 2):

Chrome Developer Tools has built in support for XPaths.

### To obtain an XPath

Open Developer Tools, and select the Elements tab.  Select targeted element, and right click, `Copy -> Copy XPath`:

[image]

### To use an XPath

In the console,

```
$x('//p')
```

will select all `p` elements in the current page.